# Как получить значение коллекции mongodb не создавая схему?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Пробовал через db.getCollection() - не получается, подскажите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `db.collection('users').find({})`

Comment: мне прилетает обьект "Cursor", это не то что я ожидаю получить

Comment: Использовать курсор `db.collection('users').find({}).toArray()`. Или использовать `findOne` - если документ 1. Лучше выделить время и прочитать документацию, потому что это снимет кучу вопросов в будущем.